# Joi validations: multiple validation error messages for single field

Tags: javascript, validation, express, joi

I am trying to achieve the following validation flow through joi https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi package.

1) Check the field `category` exists if not display the error `category required`.

2)Check the category field allows only alphabets if not display the error message `provide valid category`

Here is my code

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    category: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('category is required')),
    category: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/).required().error(new Error('category is not valid')),
});
```

But it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually provide a callback to the [`error()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr-options) function and check what caused the error.

The callback in your case would look like:

```
const onError = x => {
    switch (x[0].type) {
        case 'any.required': {
            return new Error('category is required');
        }
        case 'string.regex.base': {
            return new Error('category is not valid');
        }
        default: {
            return new Error('category has some error');
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
category: Joi.string()
        .regex(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/)
        .required()
        .error(onError)
```

Here is the complete snippet I used:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const onError = x => {
    switch (x[0].type) {
        case 'any.required': {
            return new Error('category is required');
        }
        case 'string.regex.base': {
            return new Error('category is not valid');
        }
        default: {
            return new Error('category has some error');
        }
    }
};

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    category: Joi.string()
        .regex(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/)
        .required()
        .error(onError)
});

const testCategories = [{ category: 'ABCD' }, {}, { category: '&&&' }];

testCategories.forEach(aCategory => {
    schema
        .validate(aCategory)
        .then(() => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(aCategory), 'passed!');
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(aCategory), 'failed', e);
        });
});
```